# "write after end" error with Express and its json parser

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to build an API that takes a JSON input with Express. That seems quite straightforward, but I'm getting the error `[ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end`.

My (much simplified) (TypeScript) code is as follow:

```
import express from 'express';
const app = express();
const jsonParser = express.json();

app.use(async (req, res, next) => {
  // Common actions for all requests
  console.log('Raw request:', req);
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  await next();
  res.end();
});

app.post('/example', jsonParser, async (req, res) => {
  console.log('Parsed request body:', req.body);
  res.write('ok');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

When I post some JSON (simply `{"test":"test"}`), with a `Content-Type: application/json` to 127.0.0.1:3000/example, my program crashes with the "write after end" error. I've tried the following things:

1. If I set the Content-Type to something else (like text/plain), it doesn't crash, but the JSON isn't caught properly (my log "Parsed request body" shows an empty object).
2. If I remove the `res.write('ok');`, it doesn't crash either (and returns an empty string), but this means I'm not able to return stuff, which isn't acceptable.
3. If I remove the whole `app.use(...)` section, it works fine, but I'd really like to be able to do some pre- +/- post-processing on all routes there, so that's not a satisfying option either.

Is there something I'm doing wrong, or is it just impossible to do what I'm trying to do and I should stick with option number 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the `error` is *expected*. You're writing to `response` stream after *closing* (or ending) it.

```
await next(); // <-- This is calling you next middleware
res.end(); // meanwhile this is executed and closes the stream
```

You can do like:

```
app.use(async (req, res, next) => {
  // Common actions for all requests
  console.log('Raw request:', req);
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  next();
});

app.post('/example', jsonParser, async (req, res) => {
  console.log('Parsed request body:', req.body);
  res.write('ok');
  res.end();
});
```

Comment: It works, but I don't get it: isn't `await` supposed to make the execution hold until whatever is called is done? For instance, with Koa they do this to measure execution time https://koajs.com/#cascading

Comment: `express`'s *next* does not return a `promise`, so `await` is not going to wait execution